# ¿Qué significa la frase "La ruta es muy pesada"?

Tags: adjetivos, perú

What is the meaning of:

> La ruta es **muy pesada**

In the documentary *Andes Magicos* one of the truck drivers describes the route between a city and a remote Peruvian village as **muy pesada**.

> La ruta es muy pesada, transitada.

What is the meaning of a 'very heavy route'?

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of transit, it's used when a road has few lanes or has a lot of vehicular congestion.
In other contexts it's used when a village for example is located high above sea level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if **pesada** have got a special meaning in Perú but you can interpret it in that sentence as one of these taken from the DRAE

**[pesado/a](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SlsZN3g)**

> 6. adj. Tardo o **muy lento**.
> 7. adj. Molesto, enfadoso, impertinente.
> 8. adj. Aburrido, que no tiene interés.

@fedorqui points

> 11. adj. Duro, violento, insufrible, difícil de soportar.

It may be but I interpret the sentence as

> La ruta es muy pesada, [porque está muy] transitada

I've highlighted the most probable one: **muy lento**. If the road is narrow, in bad conditions and has got high traffic, you may spend a lot of time to travel it. You move along it at a **slow** [lento] speed.

Either way, we can not translate it as "heavy" in that context.

Comment: Yo apostaría por _11. adj. Duro, violento, insufrible, difícil de soportar._. Así lo he oído usar por colombianos, si bien no lo encuentro en el Damer.

Comment: Puede ser, la añado, habría que ver el documental. Quizás la 7 "molesto" sería un grado menor de "insufrible". Yo interpreto la frase como "La ruta es muy pesada porque está muy transitada". La violencia y la dureza no aparecerían.

Comment: In this context I think 11 is most appropriate because the route is steep, narrow, and very dangerous, with little room for oncoming traffic to pass. The meaning to me seems to be a combination of defintion 11 and the response luis199230 gave.

Comment: It should be no ambiguity, since the question includes the quoted statement "la ruta es muy pesada, transitada". The flow is slow and difficult (heavy) due to the number of vehicles on it

Comment: @user2325442 I don't get how you remove the ambiguity so easily. That word have 15 different meanings. How do you know which one has been employed by the speaker?

Comment: We can no say for sure. But the most probable meaning might be here determined by the traffic allusion (the route being 'transitada")

Answer (score 1):

"La ruta **es** muy pesada" sounds odd to me because the verb "ser" would indicate that being congested is a permanent feature of the road. In that case, I'd use a demonstrative or some name for the road to be clearly identified as the one that has a lot of traffic (as opposed to others that don't):

- **Esta** ruta es muy pesada.
- La ruta **entre Lima e Iquitos** es muy pesada.

Otherwise, my feeling is that "está" would sound more natural, to mean that the road currently used is congested at the moment:

- La ruta **está** muy pesada.